# H10 - App crashed error while deploying Selenium Python scraper on Heroku

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

**Python application**

**Proc file:**

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

**Requirement:**

```
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
requests==2.27.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
flask==2.0.3
selenium==4.1.2
```

**Error**

```
2022-04-12T15:27:32.877398+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=scraper-papersdrop.herokuapp.com request_id=f189ac84-cfd8-4bec-9226-741250314389 fwd="157.51.25.187" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-04-12T15:27:33.499233+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=scraper-papersdrop.herokuapp.com request_id=e7069e84-f6b4-4bc6-a4b1-7f4164efa674 fwd="157.51.25.187" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: What do your error logs say before those two lines?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
2022-04-12T15:27:32.877398+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=scraper-papersdrop.herokuapp.com request_id=f189ac84-cfd8-4bec-9226-741250314389 fwd="157.51.25.187" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

...indicates a crashed web dyno or a boot timeout on the web dyno.

---

### Deep Dive

Heroku returns a standard error page with the HTTP status code ***503***. To assist in debuging the underlying error the platform also adds the custom error information along with its own error code, with all HTTP errors starting with the letter ***H*** and all runtime errors starting with ***R***. Logging errors start with ***L***.

Another example:

```
2010-10-06T21:51:12-07:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd=17.17.17.17 dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

---

### 503 Service Unavailable

The [HTTP 503 Service Unavailable](https://www.itpro.co.uk/web-browser/30394/what-is-http-error-503-and-how-do-you-fix-it) server error response code indicates that the server is not in a state to handle the client request.

Some of the common causes are a server that is down for maintenance or that is overloaded with other requests. Ideally, this response should be used for temporary conditions and the [`Retry-After`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) HTTP header possibly should, contain the estimated time for the recovery of the service.

---

### This usecase

However in this usecase it seems:

- *`protocol=https`*
- *`host=scraper-papersdrop.herokuapp.com`*
- *`dyno=`*
- *`desc="App crashed"`*
- *`status=503`*

which implies that the application wasn't deployed successfully.